# Star designation

Tags: star, stellar-evolution, star-catalogues

There are several designations for most of the stars (left column in the picture). What is the name of designation for names like Alnilam, Sirius, Alhara ... How to call these names? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Textual information including such tables should be added as text - not as image. Images are not searchable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple: those are the names of the named stars, also called '[proper names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_proper_names_of_stars)'. All other designations you show in your table are catalogue numbers assigned to them.

While these names are historically grown, the official names are assigned / decided by the IAU to avoid confusion and standardize them.